# Early to mid 70's 2-player maze race game - What was the name?

Tags: identify-this-game

It's not Pathfinder.
This one came with a vertical red plastic board that had pegs on half of each side with which you would build a maze using several dozen white "T"-shaped blocks placed between 2 pegs. When your maze was complete, you would close the clear plastic door, covering the whole playing field, to lock the pegs in place. Your opponent did the same thing on their side.  The other half of your board was the back of the other player's maze and you had a magnetic tool that you used to pick up a steel ball from the bottom of the playing area and blindly navigate their maze until you hit a block and the ball fell. Then it was the other person't turn.  Your maze had to have a navigable path to a hole in the board, near the top, that, if you successfully solved the maze, you would retrieve the ball bearing through. First one to do so, won the game.

Comment: You can hit the check mark next to his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about [Mind Maze](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/5463/mind-maze).